# Xamarin.Forms: Skip Source in a Binding on custom ContentView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding, custom-view

I'm trying to create a ContentView containing a `CheckBox` and `Label`. When you click the label the Checkbox should be toggled.

Now the problem I have with my code, is that each time you want to use the checkbox, you have to rebase the BindingContext, or else it won't work.

You have to specify the source (= MainPage.BindingContext):

```
<controls:CheckBox
    Text="Hello world"
    IsChecked="{Binding BindingContext.PanelsVisible,
                   Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type app:MainPage}},
                   Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And cannot simply write:

```
<controls:CheckBox
    Text="Hello world"
    IsChecked="{Binding PanelsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

You'd get the following error:

```
[0:] Binding: 'PanelsVisible' property not found on 'Example.Xamarin.Forms.Controls.CheckBox', target property: 'Example.Xamarin.Forms.Controls.CheckBox.IsChecked'
```

So he's looking for the `PanelsVisible` property on my checkbox instead of my viewmodel (why?).

How can I rewrite this so that I don't have to specify the Source each time I'm using my checkbox?

I created a [repository here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.Xamarin.Forms.Controls)

### Code

Code behind:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CheckBox : ContentView
{
    public CheckBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    #region IsChecked
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsCheckedProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(CheckBox), false, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
    {
        var control = (CheckBox)bindable;
        control.IsChecked = (bool)newValue;
    });

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Text
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(CheckBox), "", BindingMode.OneWay, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
    {
        var control = (CheckBox)bindable;
        control.Text = (string)newValue;
    });

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsChecked = !IsChecked;
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MintPlayer.Xamarin.Forms.Controls"
         
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:BindingContext="{x:Static controls:CheckBox}"
         
             x:Class="MintPlayer.Xamarin.Forms.Controls.CheckBox">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceEventName=CheckedChanged}" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" Padding="0,5,0,0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

And so I can use my custom checkbox like this:

Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:app="clr-namespace:MintPlayer.Xamarin.Forms.Controls.Demo"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MintPlayer.Xamarin.Forms.Controls;assembly=MintPlayer.Xamarin.Forms.Controls"
             x:Class="MintPlayer.Xamarin.Forms.Controls.Demo.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <app:MainVM />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        <controls:CheckBox Text="Hello world" IsChecked="{Binding BindingContext.PanelsVisible, Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type app:MainPage}}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <!-- I want to write this -->
        <!-- <controls:CheckBox Text="Hello world" IsChecked="{Binding PanelsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" /> -->
        <Switch IsToggled="{Binding PanelsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Frame IsVisible="{Binding PanelsVisible}" BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainVM : BaseModel
{
    private bool panelsVisible;
    public bool PanelsVisible
    {
        get => panelsVisible;
        set => SetProperty(ref panelsVisible, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom control XAML file, note the tag `<ContentView.Content>`.

So in your custom control constructor, please change to `Content.BindingContext = this;`.

Then it works.

`<controls:CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding PanelsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="Hello world" />`

---

Btw, refactor the IsChecked region a bit.

1. When you bind to itself and nothing fancy for property changed, you can dismiss that part
2. Use "nameof(IsChecked)" instead of a string value.

```
        #region IsChecked
        public static readonly BindableProperty IsCheckedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsChecked), typeof(bool), typeof(CheckBox), false, BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
            set => SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: Thanks `Content.BindingContext = this` did it for me. Also the `propertyChanged` callbacks aren't necessary anymore like you said